# Trouble executing my class crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, web-scraping

I'm completely newbie to python when it comes to scrape any web data using class. So, apology in advance for any serious mistake. I've written a script to parse the text using `a` tag from wikipedia web site. I tried to write the code accurately from my level best but for some reason when i execute the code it throws error. The code and the error I'm having are given below for your kind consideration.

The script:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

class TextParser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.link = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page'
        self.storage = None

    def fetch_url(self):
        self.storage = requests.get(self.link).text

    def get_text(self):
        root = fromstring(self.storage)
        for post in root.cssselect('a'):
            print(post.text)

item = TextParser()
item.get_text()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\testmatch.py", line 38, in <module>
    item.get_text()
  File "C:\Users\mth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\testmatch.py", line 33, in get_text
    root = fromstring(self.storage)
  File "C:\Users\mth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 875, in fromstring
    is_full_html = _looks_like_full_html_unicode(html)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing the following two lines

```
item = TextParser()
item.get_text()
```

When you initialize `TextParser`, `self.storage` is equal to None. When you execute the function get_text() it's still equal to None. So that's why you get that error.

However, if you change it to the following. `self.storage` should get populated with a string rather than being none.

```
item = TextParser()
item.fetch_url()
item.get_text()
```

If you want to call the function get_text without calling fetch_url you can do it this way.

```
def get_text(self):
    self.fetch_url()
    root = fromstring(self.storage)
    for post in root.cssselect('a'):
        print(post.text)
```

Comment: Thanks sir Jonathan, it works now. Gonna accept it as an answer soon. Please don't ignore giving the advice as to how I can execute the scraper without calling `fetch_url()`. This is what I tried in the first place. Thanks and much obliged.

Comment: Well, you could call fetch_url in the function get_text.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was it.